# Getting SOAPProcessingException in my webserice

Tags: java, web-services

I am building a wrapper webservice using Axis2 1.3 for an existing sharepoint webservice. Once i build the web service client, i write a test class to invoke the sharepoint webservice to retrieve a list of items; what am running into is an exception stack which says "org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html"

please find the code below:

```
---------------------------

ListsStub proxy = new ListsStub();

HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();

List schemes = new ArrayList();

schemes.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);
auth.setAuthSchemes(schemes);
auth.setUsername("username");
auth.setPassword("password");
auth.setDomain("domain");
auth.setHost("host");

/*proxy._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED,
Boolean.FALSE);*/

proxy._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,
auth);

GetListItems getListItems = new com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.ListsStub.GetListItems();
GetListItemsResponse response = new GetListItemsResponse();

response = proxy.GetListItems(getListItems);

    Please refer the Exception stack as follows :

----------------
```

> ```
>     [INFO] OMException in getSOAPBuilder
>     org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:219)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:177)
>     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:163)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:161)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:609)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:178)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:111)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:87)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:326)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:389)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:211)
>     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
>     at com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.ListsStub.GetListItems(ListsStub.java:2288)
>     at com.uboc.test.TestingWS.main(TestingWS.java:40)
>     Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
>     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:417)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:89)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:326)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:389)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:211)
>     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
>     at com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.ListsStub.GetListItems(ListsStub.java:2288)
>     at com.uboc.test.TestingWS.main(TestingWS.java:40)
>     Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:219)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:177)
>     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:163)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:161)
>     at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:609)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:178)
> ```

```
    What is the cause of this problem? How do i fix this? Please advice and help.
```

Comment: Maybe you have an authentification problem, the error suggests the page is starting by html unlikely to be the WSDL of your web service